# Fiber Bundle with a perfect bilinear map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, fibre-bundles

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ a double cover of Riemann surfaces, and consider a $SL_n-$bundle $E$ with a perfect $\mathcal O_Y-$bilinear pairing $$\psi:\pi_*E\times\pi_*E\rightarrow\pi_*\mathcal O_X$$
which verifies $\psi(av,w)=\psi(v,\sigma(a)w)$ and $\psi(v,w)=\sigma(\psi(w,v))$, where $\sigma:X\rightarrow X$ is the canonical involution.

My question is:

- Is this the same as given a perfet bilinear form on $E$?
- and How could we translate this propriety to the transition functions of $E$?

Thanks

Comment: Every time I answer one of your questions, you delete the question.

Comment: May I ask what perfect bilinear pairing means in the question. For me, a bilinear pairing $A\otimes_R B\to C$ of $R$-modules is perfect if the adjoint map $A\to Hom_R(B,C)$ is an isomorphism. In your question, $\pi_\ast \mathcal{O}_X$ has rank two, so the ranks of the corresponding bundles don't match.

Comment: @Jason Starr, sorry if did that, but just i delete the questions that have a negative rank!!

Comment: Okay, then that is fine with me.  I did not consider that aspect.